# Truth Table - Converting boolean value to 1 and 0

Tags: java, binary, boolean-logic, truthtable

I am currently working through the work book, Java A Beginners Guide.  Chapter 2 has a little project to create a truth table.  The values that are displayed are in the format of true or false.  The goal is to display 1's and 0's instead.

I have tried the below code to do this but the `String.valueOf` method wont work for all of the expressions.  I am out of idea's as to how i can do this.

```
package ChapterTwo;

public class LogicalOpTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean p, q;

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

    p = true; q = true;

    String str0 = String.valueOf(p);
    String str1 = String.valueOf(q);

    str0 = true ? "1" : "2";
    str1 = true ? "1" : "2";

    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

    p = true; q = false;
    System.out.print(str0 + "\t" + str1 +"\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

    p = false; q = true;
    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

    p = false; q = false;
    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the hints and tips, in the end my final code looks like the below.
I know there are probably easier ways to do this but the book wants you to utilize all the stuff from the first two chapters, so i have included a control statement as well.

Please up vote if you think it is OK.

Thanks
// Try this 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators.
package ChapterTwo;

```
public class LogicalOpTable {
public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean p, q;
    int a = 0, b = 0;

System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

p = true; q = true;
    if(p) a = 1;
    else a = 0;
    if(q) b = 1;
    else b = 0;
    System.out.print(a + "\t" + b +"\t");
    System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = true; q = false;
    if(p) a = 1;
    else a = 0;
    if(q) b = 1;
    else b = 0;
    System.out.print(a + "\t" + b +"\t");
    System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = false; q = true;
    if(p) a = 1;
    else a = 0;
    if(q) b = 1;
    else b = 0;
    System.out.print(a + "\t" + b +"\t");
    System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = false; q = false;
    if(p) a = 1;
    else a = 0;
    if(q) b = 1;
    else b = 0;
    System.out.print(a + "\t" + b +"\t");
    System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));
}
public static String printBoolean(boolean p) {
    return p ? "1" : "0";
}
public static String printBoolean2(boolean q) {
    return q ? "1" : "0";
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need `a` or `b` variable.

Comment: I don't know how i could have been so stupid.
After a long lay off i have now come back to this problem and see the point Gael is making.

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake writing this :

```
str0 = true ? "1" : "2";
str1 = true ? "1" : "2";
```

You probably meant :

```
str0 = (str0 == "true") ? "1" : "2";
str1 = (str1 == "true") ? "1" : "2";
```

But you can even do it quicker (and remove first assignation when creating `str0` and `str1`) :

```
str0 = p ? "1" : "2";
str1 = q ? "1" : "2";
```

**EDIT** : Also note that you'll have to recompute `str0` and `str1` when changing values of `p` or `q` if you want to. So you might want to write a subfunction as @DThought answered.

**EDIT 2** : The subfonction could be the following :

```
static String printBoolean(boolean b) {
    return b ? "1" : "2";
}
```

And use this function in your main code like this :

```
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean(p|q) + "\t");
```

Also note that you don't need to write 4 times the same piece of code. You could create loops to iterate over each values of `(p,q)`.

Comment: Thanks for the above, but it does not answer my question.  You cannot evaluate the str0 and str1 variables in all of those expressions, so what is the easiest way to show 1 and 0 instead of true or false?

Answer (score 0):

try to make the following method:
private static String convert(boolean bool);

set up that method in a way, it'll return you "0" and "1" for false and true, and then use that method in your print constructs at any place, where you're prining out boolean values.

Comment: I have tried setting up a method but i still cannot get the expressions to evaluate correctly, could you please give me more of an example?

Answer (score 0):

after a long lay off i now understand Gael,s comment and the answer a lot better, i don't know how i could have been so stupid.  Please see updated code below and please up vote back up.  Thanks,

```
package ChapterTwo;

 // Try this 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators. package   ChapterTwo;

public class LogicalOpTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean p, q;

System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

p = true; q = true;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = true; q = false;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = false; q = true;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = false; q = false;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));
}
public static String printBoolean(boolean p) {
return p ? "1" : "0";
}
public static String printBoolean2(boolean q) {
    return q ? "1" : "0";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LogicalOpTabl {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    boolean p, q;
    String a;

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

    p = true;
    q = true;
    a = ((p ? 1 : 0) + "\t" + (q ? 1 : 0) +"\t" + ((p&q)? 1 : 0) + "\t" + ((p|q)? 1:0) + "\t" + ((p^q)? 1 :0) + "\t" + ((!p)? 1 :0));
    System.out.println(a);

    p = true;
    q = false;
    System.out.println((p ? 1 : 0) + "\t" + (q ? 1 : 0) +"\t" + ((p&q)? 1 : 0) + "\t" + ((p|q)? 1:0) + "\t" + ((p^q)? 1 :0) + "\t" + ((!p)? 1 :0));

    p = false;
    q = true;
    System.out.println((p ? 1 : 0) + "\t" + (q ? 1 : 0) +"\t" + ((p&q)? 1 : 0) + "\t" + ((p|q)? 1:0) + "\t" + ((p^q)? 1 :0) + "\t" + ((!p)? 1 :0));

    p = false;
    q = false;
    System.out.println((p ? 1 : 0) + "\t" + (q ? 1 : 0) +"\t" + ((p&q)? 1 : 0) + "\t" + ((p|q)? 1:0) + "\t" + ((p^q)? 1 :0) + "\t" + ((!p)? 1 :0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also working through that book and was dissapointed to find that there is no answer to this question in the book or in the Oracle listings that can be downloaded.

Anywho, I am a total programmer noob. Just started with this book last week and totally got stuck on this question.

This is the best solution I could come up with by using only what I learned from the book up to this point (2-2 question 6)

```
class LogicalOpTable6 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean p, q;

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

    p = true; q = true;
    if(p)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!q)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p&q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p&q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p|q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p|q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p^q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p^q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.println("1");
    if(!(!p))
        System.out.println("0");

    /* System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p)); */

    p = true; q = false;
    if(p)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!q)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p&q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p&q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p|q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p|q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p^q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p^q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.println("1");
    if(!(!p))
        System.out.println("0");

    /* System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p)); */

    p = false; q = true;
    if(p)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!q)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p&q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p&q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p|q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p|q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p^q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p^q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.println("1");
    if(!(!p))
        System.out.println("0");

    /* System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p)); */

    p = false; q = false;
    if(p)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!q)
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p&q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p&q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p|q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p|q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(p^q)
        System.out.print("1" + "\t");
    if(!(p^q))
        System.out.print("0" + "\t");
    if(!p)
        System.out.println("1");
    if(!(!p))
        System.out.println("0");

    /* System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p)); */
}
```

It's a lot of lines, I'm well aware, but after typing the if statements for row one of the truth table they could be copied for the other three rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LogicalOpTable {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT(P)");

                    boolean P, Q;
            
           
                P = true;
                Q = true;

                    if(P) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P&Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P|Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P^Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(!P) {
                           System.out.print("1\n");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\n");
                    }
                    
                    
                P = true;
                    Q = false;
            
                    if(P) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P&Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P|Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P^Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(!P) {
                           System.out.print("1\n");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\n");
                    }
                    

            P = false;
                    Q = true;
            
                    if(P) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P&Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P|Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P^Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(!P) {
                           System.out.print("1\n");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\n");
                    }
                    

                P = false;
                Q = false;
            
                    if(P) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P&Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P|Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(P^Q) {
                           System.out.print("1\t");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\t");
                    }
                    if(!P) {
                           System.out.print("1\n");
                    }
                    else { System.out.print("0\n");
                    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: You are basically hard-coding the answer which doesn’t make much sense from the exercise point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the solution:

```
// Try this 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators.
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int p, q;
        boolean b;

        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

        p = 1; q = 1;
        b = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + ((p*-p)+1));

        p = 1; q = 0;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + ((p*-p)+1));

        p = 0; q = 1;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + ((p*-p)+1));

        p = 0; q = 0;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + ((p*-p)+1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is somehow right, at least it's working :)

```
    class LogicalOpTable {
    static String printBoolean(boolean b) {
        return b ? "1" : "0";
}
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        boolean p, q;
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

        p = true; q = true;
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + printBoolean(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(printBoolean(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean(!p));

        p = true; q = false;
        //int val3 = (p) ? 1 : 0;
        //int val4 = (q) ? 1 : 0;
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + printBoolean(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(printBoolean(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean(!p));

        p = false; q = true;
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + printBoolean(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(printBoolean(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean(!p));

        p = false; q = false;
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + printBoolean(q) + "\t");
        System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean(p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println(printBoolean(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean(!p));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).